# python in-line for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm wondering if there is a way in python to use a simplified, in-line for loop to do different things.
For example:

```
for x in range(5):
    print(x)
```

to be written in a simpler form, such as

```
print (x) for x in range(5)
```

but this does not seem to be working.

I've been googling for finding the right syntax for a couple hours without success. The only alternative I found is, when the in-line for loop is used to access elements of a list:

```
print ([x for x in range(5)])
```

is working, but it is doing something else, than what I'm looking for.

Can someone point to the right syntax or let me know if there are any restrictions? (maybe in-line for loops work only about lists?)

Comment: Do you want list comprehensions? If not, then no, there isnt such a thing in python.

Comment: `for x in range(5): print(x)` - All on one line. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: In Python 3.x, as `print` is a function, you could do `list(map(print, range(5)))`, or `[print(x) for x in range(5)]`. But I don't see why you would!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

There is no such a thing as "in line for loops" in python

**A trick that works:**

in python 3.*:

```
[print(x) for x in range(5)]
```

Because `print` is a function

In python 2.* `print`is not a function but you could define `myprint` and use it like this:

```
>>> def myprint(x):
...     print x
... 
>>> _=[ myprint(x) for x in range(5)]
0
1
2
3
4
```

**More in depth:**

What you call "in-line for loops" or "shortforms" are  actually [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and (quoting documentation)

> provide a concise way to create lists

The first part of a list comprehension (before the `for`keyword) must contain an expression used to create list values. If your expression contains a function that has the (side) effect of printing something it works... but it is exactly a side effect. What you are really doing is creating a list and then discarding it.

Note that you can't assign values (like `q += (x * y)`) in a list comprehension because assignments are not expressions.

Comment: Thanks! However if I want to generalize the solution it still does not appear to be working - see example: 
`q=0 
[q += (x*y) for x in range(3) for y in range(5)] 
print(q)` 
what am I missing on about how to use the shortforms?

Comment: @Adam: you can't use assignments in list comprehensions. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your items with new line character and print it.But this is not a proper way for just printing I recommend the your first code using a simple loop.

```
>>> print '\n'.join([str(x) for x in range(5)]) 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Or since `map` performs better at dealing with built-in functions rather than list comprehension you can use `map(str, range(5))`

The result would be your first code :

```
>>> for x in range(5):
...     print(x)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

You can also do it in one line :

```
>>> for x in range(5):print(x)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Or `map(str, range(5))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed added to answer!